# what are the correct tools to create a cube from SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas-2012

I am new to this field. I am trying to create a cube from SQL Server 2012. I generally know how to create a cube using Visual Studio 2010. But I can not find Visual Studio 2010 to download (or to buy). The IT person can provider Visual Studio 2015, but I do not know which version do I need (Visual Studio Community, Visual Studio Professional, or Visual Studio Enterprise?).

I downloaded the free version of SQL Server 2012 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50003
But we did not install all of the features (see image 1 below)

When I create a new project in SQL management studio, it looks like image 2.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thank you very much!

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download this version of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to get the templates to create a cube, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843.

It installs a Visual Studio shell if you don't have Visual Studio installed already. It's enough to use the cube project templates. SSDT is all you need to start develop cubes, tabular models, Integration Services packages, and Reporting Services solutions.

Comment: "Installs Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence project templates for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services that support Visual Studio 2012." I do not have Visual Studio 2012, or Visual Studio 2010. So, do I install this anyway?

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it out.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015 Community (free) ... once that was installed I opened it and it showed a message asking if I wanted to install certain updates - one of which was SSDT. So all free and pretty easy to do. I think my colleague did SSDT first then tried to add VS 2015 Community afterwards and had some issues - so I recommend 1 unistall previous VS versions installed 2 install VS 2015 Comm 3 From inside VS 2015 install SSDT.

Comment: Hello Ola, I've already created cubes successfully in the Visual Studio shell and now I am trying to deploy it. But every time I tried, the deployment failed. I double checked the path of the server under Property/Deployment/Target/Server and it is correct. Can you let me know what are the possible reasons? Thanks!

Comment: @FeifeiZhang if the deployment target is correct I would guess that it's the impersonation setting on the data source connection that needs to be looked at. I would start a new questions and include the error message.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl I will start a new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2012, you should use Visual Studio 2010 to create cubes.

Comment: I know this. But I do not where to get Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Data Tools installed so that you can create an Analysis Services Project.

See this article for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451750/Installing-SQL-Server-Data-Tools-SSDT